# Is my ex step father still my mahram?

Tags: non-mahram, mahram

as salaamu alaikum, Since my mother is now divorced to her ex-husband this is not my father, we still communicate. Does this mean he is no longer considered my mahram? Should I adjust my behavior around him now that he's no longer my mother's husband? How does this dynamic work? Jazakallah khair for your help.

Comment: He is your biological father or step-father? Also please format your question properly into sentences and paragraphs, avoid irrelevant chatter, and put the actual question in the title.

Comment: okay I edited it. he’s not my father was just my stepfather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your step-father consummated his marriage with your mother then he has become your mahram **permanently** - this means he will remain your mahram even after separation from your mother.

> ربائبكم اللاتي في حجوركم من نسائكم اللاتي دخلتم بهن فإن لم تكونوا دخلتم بهن فلا جناح عليكم
>
> (forbidden are) your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in unto them, there is no sin upon you.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23?translations=20)</sup>

> واتفقوا على أن الرجل إذا دخل بزوجته، حرمت عليه بنتها على التأبيد
>
> The scholars are agreed that if a man has intercourse with his wife then her daughter will be forbidden to him forever
>
> <sup>— [Ikhtilaaf al-A’immah al-‘Ulama](https://shamela.ws/book/6228/587)</sup>

It will always remain forbidden for you two to be married to each other. Also by default you do not need to veil yourself from him and you can be alone with him, shake hands with him and travel with him - provided that there is safety from fitnah i.e. you both do not feel any desire towards each other.

**Ref:** https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/330802/ and https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/42029/